# How to design the model classes for a relational database using JSON

Tags: database, json, class, relation, relational

I want to design the classes for a relational DB. The main problem is how to design the Foreign Keys. For example we got this:

```
Client:
   -(PK)id
   -name
   -(FK)car_id

Car:
   -(PK)id
   -name
```

We can code a reference from the class Client to the class Car, or simply code an attribute "carId" in the class Client.

The problem is that I want to get send this objects in a JSON response, so, if we use the reference solution, the reference to Car will be null or the Car object will be repeated tons of times.

What's the best approach?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure to anerstand properly. WHat's the problem about using the foreign ID? It's basically a string, no issue to convert it into JSON.

Comment: I want to use references in the classes instead of using a foreign ID